# What does 欠かせない mean here?

Tags: grammar

外国人人材が日本の産業に**欠かせない**存在になる中、どうやって優秀な人材を獲得し、定着してもらうのか。企業だけでなく、国としても戦略を考える時がきているのかもしれない…取材を通じてそう感じました。

The two verbs that it could be (欠かす and 欠く) are transitive but in this sentence it doesn't seem to be a transitive verb...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[欠かせない](https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E6%AC%A0%E3%81%8B%E3%81%9B%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84) means "essential" "indispensable" "necessary".

Dictionary form -- 欠かす (transitive) "miss" "lack"
→ Potential form -- 欠かせる*
→ Negative Potential -- 欠かせない "can't miss/lack" → "essential"
* <sub>([可能]かかせる is mentioned in [デジタル大辞泉「欠かす」](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/37848/meaning/m0u/%E6%AC%A0%E3%81%8B%E3%81%99/). Usually used in the negative form.)</sub>

I'm pretty sure you know you can use "object + が + transitive potential", as in:

> 「（私は）日本語**が**話**せ**ます。」 "I can speak Japanese."

Likewise, you could say:

> 「外国人人材**が**欠か**せ**ない」
>   "(we) can't lack / do without foreign workers" → "foreign workers are indispensable"

... But your example should be parsed:

> 外国人人材が｛（日本の産業に欠かせない）存在に｝なる

外国人人材 is the subject of なる, not 欠かせない. （日本の産業に欠かせない modifies 存在.）

---

欠かせない〇〇 can be rephrased as 欠かすことのできない〇〇, or 欠くことのできない〇〇 using transitive 欠く.